# RabbitMQ: Message acked by exchange without any existing bindings to it

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I´m sending a message to a topic exchange which hasn´t any bindings to any queues. Just a blank exchange.
The channel is created as confirm channel and my confirm callback is called each time I send a message.
The strange thing is that for each message I get ack.

Am I doing something wrong or missunderstand the way how publisher confirmation works?
How can I know if a message is routed to a queue or dropped by the exchange?

I´m using amqplib for node.

---

Ok probably I didn´t explain my issue clear enough. So here is some code:

```
var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
amqp.connect('amqp://host' , function(err, conn) {

    conn.createConfirmChannel(function(err, ch) {

        channel.assertExchange('my_awsome_exchange', 'topic', {durable: true});

        channel.publish('my_awsome_exchange', 'routing_key', new Buffer('some data'),
        {
            mandatory: true
        },
        function(err){
           // err is null no matter if a queue is bound to the exchange or not
           console.log(err);
        });
    });
});
```

As you can see an exchange is created but no queue is bound to this exchange yet. So my expectation was that sending messages to this exchange would never be acked. 
@Teddy: I know this section from the docs and this is the reason why I´m so confused.
As the message isn´t routed to any queue I would have expected the message to be nacked.

Comment: is it possible for you to share sample code? check it. might be you were using `$queue->ack($message['delivery_tag']);`

Comment: What is "blank exchange" ? Are you talking about a nameless exchange? Or default "amqp.topic" exchange or what? You have a lot of inconsistencies here... If the callback is set to be called when message is received than clearly there must be some queue with some binding. If you are using the nameless exchange than this is direct exchange not topic!

Answer (score 13):

It is by design. Check this [link](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html). It says clearly:

> **When will messages be confirmed?**
>
> For unroutable messages, the broker
>   will issue a confirm once the exchange verifies a message won't route
>   to any queue (returns an empty list of queues). If the message is also
>   published as mandatory, the basic.return is sent to the client before
>   basic.ack. The same is true for negative acknowledgements
>   (basic.nack).
>
> For routable messages, the basic.ack is sent when a message has been
>   accepted by all the queues. For persistent messages routed to durable
>   queues, this means persisting to disk. For mirrored queues, this means
>   that all mirrors have accepted the message.

Comment: The behavior of confirm channel is even when publishing to the no-binding exchange, the publisher is still in blocking mode, it has to wait for the 'confirmation' from the broker. If as you said, it is designed to not ack in this case, the publisher will wait forever, which doesn't sounds correct, right?

Comment: Ok, I got what you mean, you mean you think it should send back a reject?

Comment: My feeling is still returning ack make more sense. Even your exchange has some bindings, but if your excahnge type is direct or topic, there are still cases that messages will not been routed to any queue coz none of the binding keys match your routing key. And the routing logic of  exchanges to queues should be transparent to the publishers.

Comment: Ok. But how can the publisher be sure wether the message is routed or not if the exchange returns ack in any case? I want my publisher to know if a message could not be routed so it can handle this in some way.

Comment: My understanding of the design (I don't mean it is correct or not) is publishers should only know the knowledge of exchanges for where to publish, how exchanges route messages is transparent to publishers. So even when using confirms or transactions, it only guarantees when there are queues should (coz of the existing of bindings and routing keys match) receive messages really received messages. If this is the principle by design, when a routing logic says a message should be ignore (coz of no bindings on the exchange), it doesn't sounds like an error, it is still a successful publishing.

Comment: @jens_h probably late to this as it's almost 4 years old but for future readers you can setup an event listener in channel on ['return'](https://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#channel_events) event in amqlib node. This goes without saying that you'd need to publish with `mandatory` field set to `true` for exchange to n/ack on `return` event.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the misunderstanding lies in the fact, that an "Ack" means that the server successfully routed the message.

But the previous statement is **false**. Ack actually means that the server was able to handle the message successfully.

You can think of it like the RabbitMQ server saying: I take responsibility for your message

"*basic.nack will only be delivered if an internal error occurs in the Erlang process responsible for a queue.*"

Quoted by the following Link
https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the channel.confirmSelect() and its doesnt garuntee that message sent to queue rather than it give guarantee that message published to exchange. If no queue is bound at that moment then RabbitMQ server will simply discard the message.